# getting error of suspend function while using coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

also, I'm calling my suspend function inside a coroutine scope, I'm getting an error that Suspends functions can only be called within a coroutine body. how's that happening?

```
  lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated{
                viewModel.tickets.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,  {
                    it?.let { data ->
                        adapter.submitData(data)
                    }
                })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you are calling suspend function inside observe lambda.

Change the order like this:

```
   viewModel.tickets.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,  { data ->
           lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated{
                data?.let { list ->
                    adapter.submitData(list)
                }
            })
    }
```